# Recursion error in django model when setting constraints

Tags: python, django, django-models

Im trying to create an app to keep track of matches however I keep getting an error when trying to create add to my match model. I want to make sure that team 1 and team 2 dont have the same players, is this the correct way to do so? How do i resolve my error?

> ```
> team1_names = set([player.playerName for player in self.team1.all()])
>                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^ …
> Local vars
> Variable  Value
> self      Error in formatting: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a 
>             Python object
> ```

```
class player(models.Model):
    playerName = models.CharField(max_length = 255,primary_key = True)
    club = models.ForeignKey(club,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    inGameFlag = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    elo = models.IntegerField(default = 1200)

class session(models.Model):
    sessionID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    club = models.ForeignKey(club,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(default = get_today)
    players = models.ManyToManyField(player)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)
    
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['sessionID', 'club'], name='unique_session')
        ]

class match(models.Model):
    matchID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    session = models.ForeignKey(session,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team1 = models.ManyToManyField(player, related_name='team1')
    team2 = models.ManyToManyField(player, related_name='team2')
    score = models.CharField(max_length = 255, default = '00-00')
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def clean(self):
        
        team1_names = set([player.playerName for player in self.team1.all()])
        team2_names = set([player.playerName for player in self.team2.all()])

        common_players = team1_names.intersection(team2_names)

        if common_players:
            raise ValidationError({'team1': 'Players cannot be in both team1 and team2.'})
        if self.team1.count() > 2 or self.team2.count() > 2:
            raise ValueError("Each team can have a maximum of 2 players.")
        
    def __str__(self):
        team1_names = ', '.join([player.playerName for player in self.team1.all()])
        team2_names = ', '.join([player.playerName for player in self.team2.all()])
        return f"{self.matchID} - Team1: {team1_names} - Team2: {team2_names} - {self.completed}"
    
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['matchID', 'session'], name='unique_match')
        ]
```